# Make multiple dialogs on the same page co-exist better

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, popups

I had already typed a fairly long comment in the "Other" section of the Flag dialog for an answer when it occurred to me that I needed to include a link to another answer on the same page. Without thinking I clicked the Share link and of course the first dialog closed and with it went all my text. I hoped it might reappear if I reopened the Flag dialog, but no such luck. :(

I know this is not a bug per se and probably by design, but is there any way this experience can be improved? Perhaps let multiple dialogs be opened and layered one on top of the other, or a warning to the user that typed text will be lost if a dialog is closed on clicking outside, or make the dialog modal or some such thing?

Comment: I would like to see a feature where custom reasons do not vanish entirely until you navigate away from the page. That would allow someone to close out of the box and reopen it to their custom close reason (if they hadn't navigated away).